# How does window manager rendered borders from pixmap?

Tags: xlib, xorg, window-managers, xcb

Anyone could explain what is the inner means and how does window border rendered from the pixmap? thanks.

source code link: https://github.com/wmutils/opt/blob/master/chwb2.c#L72

```c
    xcb_rectangle_t inner[] = {
        /* you're not supposed to understand this. */
        {     w,0,b-o     ,h+b-   o      },
        {     w+b   +o,  0,   b  -o,     h+         b  -  o},
        {     0,h   ,w+b  -o,b-   o      },
        {     0,h   +b+      o,   w+     b-         o, b -o},
        {     w+b+o,b        +h    +o,b,b}
    };

    xcb_rectangle_t outer[] = {
        {w + b - o, 0, o, h + b * 2},
        {w + b,     0, o, h + b * 2},
        {0, h + b - o, w + b * 2, o},
        {0, h + b,     w + b * 2, o},
        {1, 1, 1, 1}
    };

    xcb_pixmap_t pmap = xcb_generate_id(conn);
    xcb_create_pixmap(conn, geom->depth, pmap, win,
            geom->width  + (b*2),
            geom->height + (b*2));
    xcb_gcontext_t gc = xcb_generate_id(conn);
    xcb_create_gc(conn, gc, pmap, 0, NULL);

    values[0] = oc;
    xcb_change_gc(conn, gc, XCB_GC_FOREGROUND, values);
    xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(conn, pmap, gc, 5, outer);

    values[0] = ic;
    xcb_change_gc(conn, gc, XCB_GC_FOREGROUND, values);
    xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(conn, pmap, gc, 5, inner);

    values[0] = pmap;
    xcb_change_window_attributes(conn, win, XCB_CW_BORDER_PIXMAP, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code creates a pixmap and then draws to it. First it fills five rectangles called `outer` with the color `oc` and then it fills another five rectangles called `inner` with the color `ic`.

To understand the meaning of each rectangle, I guess it would help to have a screenshot of what the result looks like. Then you can see in that what the various distances are and perhaps that is enough to figure out the meaning of the various rectangles.